# Popup menu hidden behind other items in FlatList

Tags: react-native-popup-menu

I have a FlatList and each item uses the react-native-popup-menu functionality to show a popup menu when clicked. However, only the top of the menu appears and the rest is hidden behind the following list items. Is there a way to have the menu appear atop the entire FlatList? Thank you.

Comment: Do you use menu provider once in the root of your component hierarchy?

Comment: I also suspect problem as @madox2 said - here is official example: https://github.com/instea/react-native-popup-menu/blob/master/examples/InFlatListExample.js